# How to reject an integer if certain digits are not wanted

Tags: c++

If i want an integer input, but if it contains any digits 2 or 3 in it, it will be rejected.

For example entering 23564 will be invalid.

I was thinking of using do-while loops to solve this, but how do I get it to read the individual digits.

Comment: to_string is the easier solution (than modulo stuff)

Comment: Use division remainder  (`%`) or convert the number to a string.

Comment: @krzaq - +1 for **not** referring to `%` as any variant of "modulus".

Comment: Or use binary. Guaranteed not to have 2's and 3's ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the *last* digit of a number with something like:

```
unsigned int number = 23456;
unsigned int digit = number % 10;  // gives 6
```

You can further "shift" all digits right with:

```
number = number / 10;              // gives 2345
```

In other words, yes, you can do it using the method you propose:

```
bool has2Or3(unsigned int number) {
    // Do until no more digits left.

    while (number != 0) {
        // Get last digit, return true if 2 or 3.

        int digit = number % 10;
        if ((digit == 2) || (digit == 3)) {
            return true;
        }

        // Prepare to get next digit.

        number = number / 10;
    }

    // If NO digits were 2 or 3, return false.

    return false;
}
```

---

Another way would be to simply convert it to a string and use the string functions to see if it contains a specific digit, something such as:

```
bool has2Or3(unsigned int number) {
    // Get number as string (via string stream).

    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << number;
    std::string s = ss.str();

    // If contains 2, return true, else continue.

    if (s.find("2") != std::string::npos)
        return true;

    // If contains 3, return true, else return false.

    return (s.find("3") != std::string::npos);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int n,num,flag;
    do{
    cout<<"Enter number";
    cin>>n;
    num = n;
    flag = 0;
    while(num>0)
    {
        if(num%10 == 2 || num%10 ==3)
        {
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
        num = num/10;
    }
    }while(flag==1);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care much about performance, you can convert the integer into a string and look for the digits. This is slower than extracting the last digit and comparing it though.

```
std::string str = std::to_string(number);
auto found2 = str.find('2');
auto found3 = str.find('3');

//number is valid if it doesn't have a 2 or a 3
bool isValid = found2 == std::string::npos && found3 == std::string::npos;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reading the input directly into an integer type, read it into a `std::string`. Then it's simple to check for unwanted digits; if the string passes the test, convert it to an integer:

```
int get_value() {
    std::string bad = "23";
    std::string input = "2"; // start with bad input
    while (std::find_first_of(input.begin(), input.end(),
        bad.begin(), bad.end()) != input.end()) {
        std::cout << "Gimme a number: ";
        std::cin >> input;
    }
    return std::stoi(input);
}
```